# Doctrine can't generate a schema when using single table inheritance?

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

An interesting problem. I'm building an application using Symfony 2 and I'm trying to get Doctrine to auto-generate my schema from my entity classes. I have two entity classes, `Invoice` and `CreditNote`. `CreditNote` extends `Invoice`. They look like this -

Invoice.php -

```
namespace My\Bundle\BillingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="invoice")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"invoice" = "Invoice", "credit_note" = "CreditNote"})
 */
class Invoice
{ ... }
```

and CreditNote.php -

```
namespace My\Bundle\BillingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CreditNote extends Invoice
{ ... }
```

...all of which seems to follow Doctrine's guidance on single table inheritance at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance.

But, when I try to run `php app/console doctrine:database:create` in order to generate my schema I get the error -

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class My\Bundle\BillingBundle\Entity\Invoice in <my-app>/src/My/Bundle/BillingBundle/Entity/Invoice.php on line 15
```

Which suggests that the `Invoice` class has already been declared (but it honestly hasn't). More interesting is that if I rename the `Invoice` class to `AInvoice` (i.e. something that comes before `CreditNote` in the alphabet, then everything works.

So, it *seems* like the generator is loading up `CreditNote.php`, finding a class that extends `Invoice` and then loading `Invoice.php`, then finding the `Invoice.php` file again and trying to parse it a second time. Only that seems the kind of thing that someone would have fixed by now.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is 100% working code - I tried just

You may need just to clean the cache using:

```
php app/console cache:clear && php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

but I use php app/console doctrine:schema:update (not doctrine:database:create)

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Clearing the cache fixed it. I just ran `php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` and tried it again. I'm surprised that's not mentioned higher up in the docs.

Comment: I didn't realise the doctrine console commands relied on the cache. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but this solution doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Can anyone please suggest whether this will fix anything if I am only using the `vendor/bin/doctrine` cli tool? I am having a similar sounding error, but I have tried clearing some caches and no difference is made

Answer (score 0):

when I had this problem I added and modified the file with the new register in the next path: Resources/config/doctrine/(EntityName.orm.yml)