# Doctrine ORM, specific class jamming CLI tool

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm, doctrine, schema

I am currently trying to add more entities to a `@MappedSuperclass`. I have the following entities

```
|-src
| | -Models
| | | -Product
| | | -**Book** (CULPRIT)
| | | -Furniture
```

The `Product` class is the Doctrine `@MappedSuperclass`, and I previously implemented `Furniture` to inherit from it.

Without `Book`, I can run `vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create` just fine. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885928/doctrine-cant-generate-a-schema-when-using-single-table-inheritance), but it is resolved with Symfony commands - I have excatly the same problem in that when I rename the troublesome class even slightly everything runs fine leading me to believe that the listed solution would help, however because I am not using symfony I try to run:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:query
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:result
```

(It tells me I don't have any second-level cache for other commands)

...and nothing changes.

Source for `Product`:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace WebApp\Models;

use WebApp\IComparable;

/**
 * Not sure if this is a valid DBAL attribute combination...
 * @MappedSuperClass
 */
abstract class Product implements IComparable
{

    /**
     * Mapping an integer-only primary key for each Product implementer
     * @Id @Column(type="string", unique=TRUE)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @CustomIdGenerator(class="WebApp\SkuGenerator")
     *
     * @var string
    */
    protected string $sku;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=40)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="decimal", precision=7, scale=2)
     *
     * @var float
     */
    protected float $price;


    public function __construct(string $name, float $price)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->setPrice($price);
    }

    /**
     * Implement workaround custom-comparability between product classes
     * @param Product
     */
    public function compareTo(IComparable $other): bool
    {
        if (($other instanceof $this) === false) {
            $current = end(explode('/', __CLASS__));
            $arg = end(explode('/', get_class($other)));
            throw new \TypeError('Comparing instances of different types, should both be of type ' . $current .
                ' but got argument of type : ' . $arg);
        }
        return $this->getSku() === $other->getSku();
    }


    public function getSku(): string
    {
        return $this->sku;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getPrice(): float
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(float $newPrice): void
    {
        if ($newPrice < 0.0) {
            throw new \RangeException('Cannot set price on ' . get_class($this) .
                ' "newPrice" argument ' . $newPrice . ' is equal to or below 0');
        } else {
            $this->price = $newPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

Source for `Book`:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace WebApp\Models;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @author ScottAnderson
 *
 */
class Book extends Product
{
    /**
     * @column(type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2)
     * @var float
     */
    protected float $weight;

    public const PRODUCT_TYPE = 'Book';

    public function __construct(string $name, float $price, float $weight)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $price);
        if ($weight < 0) {
            throw new \Exception("Weight argument to " . __METHOD__ . " cannot be a negative number.");
        }
        $this->weight = $weight;
    }

    public function getWeight()
    {
        return $this->weight;
    }
}
```